# React Native TouchableHighlight onFocus onBlur

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I am creating a menu for an Android TV, the Menu expands when it get focus, but when moving from one menu item to the other I get a flicker because I can't find a way to make the menu focus independent from the menu item focus.
I've tried to use a Touchable around the Flat list but then i cant move focus to the items.

```
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableHighlight, View } from 'react-native';

import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import { MaterialIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import React from 'react';

interface MenuListOption {
  name: string;
  icon: string;
}
interface MenuItemProps {
  setMenuFocus: (v: boolean) => void;
  item: MenuListOption;
  menuFocus: boolean;
}

export const homeLists: MenuListOption[] = [
  {
    name: 'HOME',
    icon: 'home-filled',
  },
  {
    name: 'MOVIES',
    icon: 'local-movies',
  },
  {
    name: 'TV SHOWS',
    icon: 'movie',
  },
];

const MenuItem = ({ setMenuFocus, item, menuFocus }: MenuItemProps): JSX.Element => {
  const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState(false);

  const onFocus = React.useCallback(() => {
    setFocus(true);
    setMenuFocus(true);
  }, [setMenuFocus]);

  const onBlur = React.useCallback(() => {
    setFocus(false);
    setMenuFocus(false);
  }, [setMenuFocus]);

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onFocus={onFocus} onBlur={onBlur} style={[styles.item, focus ? styles.itemFocused : null]}>
      <View style={styles.itemWrapper}>
        <MaterialIcons name={item.icon} size={50} color="red" />
        {menuFocus && <Text style={styles.text}>{item.name}</Text>}
      </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
};

const Menu = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [focus, setFocus] = React.useState(false);
  const colorsArray = focus ? ['gray', 'gray', 'transparent'] : ['gray', 'gray'];

  const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: MenuListOption }) => (
    <MenuItem setMenuFocus={setFocus} item={item} menuFocus={focus} />
  );

  return (
    <View style={[styles.wrapper, focus ? styles.wrapperFocused : null]}>
      <LinearGradient colors={colorsArray} start={{ x: 0, y: 0.9 }} end={{ x: 1, y: 0.9 }}>
        <View style={focus ? styles.logoFocus : styles.logo}>
          {focus && <MaterialIcons style={{ paddingRight: 20 }} name={'tv'} size={40} color={'white'} />}
          <Text style={[styles.title, focus && styles.textFocus]}>MyApp</Text>
        </View>
        <FlatList
          contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'center', flex: 1 }}
          style={styles.list}
          data={homeLists}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item) => String(item.name)}
        />
      </LinearGradient>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrapper: {
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    zIndex: 1,
    left: -200,
    transform: [{ translateX: 200 }],
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 15,
    lineHeight: 38,
    fontWeight: '400',
    textAlign: 'left',
  },
  wrapperFocused: {
    width: 900,
  },
  logo: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 20,
  },
  list: {
    flexGrow: 0,
    height: '100%',
    padding: 10,
  },
  logoFocus: {
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    marginTop: 60,
    marginLeft: 20,
  },
  textFocus: {
    fontSize: 35,
  },
  item: {
    maxWidth: 250,
    marginBottom: 40,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    left: 0,
    padding: 10,
  },
  itemFocused: {
    borderBottomColor: 'yellow',
    borderBottomWidth: 5,
  },
  itemWrapper: {
    maxWidth: 250,
    flexDirection: 'row',
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 28,
    lineHeight: 41,
    fontWeight: '600',
    marginLeft: 50,
    marginTop: 5,
  },
});

export default Menu;
```

Here is an animation of the problem:
[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVgP1.gif)

Comment: is there a ui design so that we can see how it should be implemented??

Comment: Hi @AshwithSaldanha, i added an animation with the menu and the problem.